# How NOT to bundle types of `.stories` file in the final roll-up bundle

Tags: npm, typescript-typings, rollup, rollupjs

I am using rollup to build react component [library](https://npmjs.com/react-loading-indicators) and storybook for testing out the components during development. However when bundling the production build of my library, I would not like the typescript declaration files of the **storybook files** to be included. I cannot find a way to get around this.
I have excluded the stories file in my rollup configuration but still the final bundle includes declaration files of the storybook files. Here is a snapshot of the `rollup` configuration file:

```js
export default [
    {
        input: "src/index.ts",
        output: [
            {...}
        ],
        plugins: [
            ...,
            typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" })
        ]
    },
    {
        input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
        output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
        plugins: [dts()],
        external: [/\.(stories.[tj]s[x]?)$/] // Packages that should not be in bundle
    }
];
```

When I run `npm run build --dry-run`, I still see the declaration files of the storybook files as illustrated below:

[image]

I am not sure if typescript has a way of limiting the files to build types for. I appreciate anyone that knows how to solve this.